# How can a new user with not enough rep comment on a question that the same user has previously asked while unregistered?

Tags: support, comment, reputation, new-users

I have a question about my Cross Validated post: [Polynomial regression with slope constrait in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222077/polynomial-regression-with-slope-constrait-in-r)

This question is marked as duplicate of another question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220614/linear-regression-polynom-slope-constraint-in-r). I posted previous question as well but I asked it without an account, I was unregistered. Is there any way to comment on my previous question with my new account? I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

Comment: I believe that somebody, in a comment, pointed you to the [form for merging your accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  After you do this, you will be able to manage all your posts.

Comment: Robert, please accept gung's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @whuber notes, you need to register and merge your accounts.  Here is my boilerplate text that provides the relevant information:

> Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do this in the **My Account** section of our [help center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help)), then you will be able to edit & comment on your own question.